# I dont know how to go out from the loop

Tags: android, android-camera

When I press this button:

```
case R.id.btlento:
    Timer timers = new Timer();
    timers.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cameraOn();
    },deloy1,poriod1);
        Timer timers2 = new Timer();
        timers2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cameraOff();
        }
    },deloy,poriod);
```

The methods cameraOn and cameraOff are:

```
private void cameraOff() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}

private void cameraOn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera = Camera.open();
    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

and the variables are:

```
int deloy = 2000;
int poriod = 2000;
int deloy1 = 1000;
int poriod1 = 2000;
```

All this is to make the camera flash blink, but I don't know how break the loop, because never stops.

How can i stop the loop?

Comment: Looks like you never turn the timer off?

Comment: Why not stop the timer using `cancel()`?

Comment: yes, it do, but it start again from the begining

Comment: but if I put cancel then, it only will work once

Comment: use timer.cancel(); onclick of stop

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag,

```
// member variables

private boolean cameraIsFlashing = false;
private Timer onTimer;
private Timer offTimer;

// constructor & other stuff

// button click method
case R.id.btlento:
     toggleCameraFlash();
   break;

private void toggleCameraFlash(){
    if(cameraIsFlashing){
        stopFlashing();
    } else {
        startFlashing();
    }
}

private void startFlashing(){
  cameraIsFlashing = true;
  // Start your timers
  onTimer = new Timer();
  onTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
      cameraOn();
  },deloy1,poriod1);
}

private void stopFlashing(){
  cameraIsFlashing = false;
  // Cancel / Stop your timers
  onTimer.cancel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call cancel() and purge() on thread timer to stop the thread.
as shown below.

```
private void cameraOff() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(timer != null){
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.release();
camera = null;

timer.cancel();// cancel and releases
timer.purge();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable for timer task instead of using anonymous class. First cancel timer task then cancel timer.